# How do I call python3.6 with python2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python file `test.py` that must be executed in the `python2.7` interpreter, while some other code in `main.py` requires the `python3.6` interpreter.

I had to call the `python3.6` interpreter through `test.py` to execute the code in `main.py` because main.py relies on some specific versions of libraries that are not available in `python2.7`. Also, since I'm writing an app plugin, the plugin's interpreter is only version 2.7. So I have to make cross-version calls.  And there are parameters to be passed between them.

I tried opening a subprocess through the `subprocess` module in test.py. But the following error was encountered.

Codes in test.py:

```py
import subprocess

epath = r'E:\Anaconda3\envs\***\python.exe'
fpath = r'D:\Codes\_Projects\***\main.py'

p = subprocess.call(
            [epath, fpath],
            stdin=None,
            stdout=None,
            stderr=None,
            creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            shell=False
        )

        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            print line
        p.stdout.close()
        p.wait()
```

And I got an error (in the cmd window where the subprocess executes):

```
Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00006a00 (most recent call first):
```

The path `E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/` is the directory of the `python2.7` interpreter. Slicer is the software I'm developing the plugin for. It comes with a python2.7 interpreter. My test.py must be executed with this interpreter.

I googled this error and someone say that this is due to a mismatch of environmental variables. So I printed out the environmental variables in `test.py` and here are some of them:

```
'PYTHONPATH': 'E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Slicer-4.10;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Slicer-4.10/qt-scripted-modules;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Slicer-4.10/qt-loadable-modules;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/vtkTeem;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../bin/Python;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Slicer-4.10/qt-loadable-modules/Python;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/Lib;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/Lib/lib-dynload;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/Lib/site-packages;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/.././bin/Lib/site-packages;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/.././lib/Slicer-4.10/python2.7/site-packages;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/lib/Python/Lib;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/lib/Python/Lib/lib-dynload;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python/lib/Python/Lib/site-packages;E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../bin/Python',
'PYTHONHOME': 'E:/Slicer_4.10.2/bin/../lib/Python',
'PYTHONNOUSERSITE': '1',
```

It can be seen that all environment variables related to python are under the Slicer path, which means that these are environment variables added by the python2.7 interpreter, during runtime.I'm sure for that because I didn't add them manually to the system's environment variables. Obviously they are not the environment that `python3.6` intepreter needs.

So, is there any way to reset environment variables, or run subprocesses in a cmd/powershell that has no environment variables like PYTHONPATH set?

My OS is windows 10.0.

Comment: The SyntaxError hints that it tries to load Python 2 code in Python 3 interpreter. Maybe you can edit your question and add more information, as currently there is not enough information answer what could cause the problem, as your setup is unknown.

Comment: Agree with @MikkoOhtamaa, it's very confusing to understand all the various local specific paths being referenced.

Comment: It appears that you are mixing python2 and python3 paths in ``PYTHONPATH``, is that so? Why do you have the *interpeter's* library path on ``PYTHONPATH`` in the first place? Note that the interpreter itself will *not* add these paths to ``PYTHONPATH``.

Comment: Reply @MisterMiyagi: I feel like I've found the reason. The python that comes with this Slicer software is not just a python interpreter, there are some additional temporary environment variables added, like the one above. Thank you very much.